# Babylonjs attach script to element

Tags: javascript, game-development, babylonjs

I would like to create a game, but following the concept "attach the script to element."
For example. In unity, we could create a 3d element Box. Then we can create a script called "MovingBox.cs" Then we have the ability to "attach that script" to the Box and the box starts moving. How does this concept work behind de scenes?
I think it makes usages of the concept "dependency injection" but I am not sure.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: is that a unity or babaylonjs question?

Comment: It is a programming concept question. The reference is Unity and I would to copy that concept and use it in Babylonjs, which is a library made in javascript.